# Experience of developing web version of a desktop application

Tags: language-agnostic

We are in the process of starting a web version of desktop application developed in Winforms in vs2008 with linq-to-sql.Has anyone ever done such an implementation? What issues you faced when reusing code for web version?

Answer (score 1):

if you partitioned your business logic and data layer into well-separated objects, it works well.  But if you have UI logic scattered throughout it's gonna be painful.  My advice:  separate projects and unit test for UI, Business Objects, Business Logic and Data and use interfaces between each layer.  Done it multiple times and it provides the best way .   Of course you're already tied into an existing system.

Answer (score 0):

if you design your application with n-tier architecture, thus you must have separated logic and data access and UI layers. with this architecture you don't need that write logic and data access layers. only write a new web ui for this.